# Understanding the example code from http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-is-super-sexy/

Tags: javascript

I'm perplexed as to how to follow the flow of this code.
As is probably obvious, I'm currently a relative beginner to JavaScript.

As I understand it:
the first two lines declare 2 global variables, "sexy" and "JavaScript", but don't define them.

Line 3: define the function "sexy" which takes zero arguments.

Line 4: what happens when sexy is invoked. I find the syntax on this line confusing. I read it as something like: if "ugly. Rails is HOT." is true, then pass "Sexy!" to sexy.sexy. Otherwise, pass "no Python." to sexy.sexy.

Line 6: defines the object named Javascript and its contents.

Line 7: key "sexy" : value = variable sexy,

Line 8: key "is" : value = function "sexAppeal"

Line 9: argument passed to function sexAppeal is true.

Line 10: if arguments[0] is false, then console.log "JavaScript is " + whatever this.sexy() evaluates to.

Last line: invoke the "is" function inside of the JavaScript object with zero arguments.

I'm not quite sure how to follow this all from the function call on the last line, to the point where it console.logs the final output.

Any narration would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
var sexy, 
    JavaScript;
function sexy() {
    return this.sexy ? ("ugly. Rails is HOT.","Sexy!") : "no Python.";
}
JavaScript = { 
    sexy:sexy, 
    is:function (sexAppeal) {
        sexAppeal = true;
        if (!arguments[0]) {
            console.log("JavaScript is " + this.sexy());
        }
    }
};
JavaScript.is();
```

Comment: The `something ? stuff : otherStuff` is called a ternary if statement and does almost what you think it does. It says `if this.sexy is true return ugly else return no python`.

Comment: This is a pretty ugly piece of code.  I sure wouldn't want to be learning javascript from someone who writes this way.

Comment: It's obviously not supposed to be a useful piece of code, but it demonstrates a few interesting features of JavaScript. Ternary operator, comma operator, object literals, behavior delegation, and variable # of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Narration in comments:

```
var sexy,  // declare a variable named `sexy`
    JavaScript; // and one named `JavaScript`
function sexy() { // declare a function named `sexy` which overrides the `sexy` variable
    return this.sexy ? // ternary operator condition is that `this.sexy` have a truthy value
           ("ugly. Rails is HOT.","Sexy!") : // comma operator, equivalent to 'Sexy!'
           "no Python."; // falsy result
}
JavaScript = { // initialize JavaScript to an object (with two properties)
    sexy:sexy, // property `sexy` references the function above
    is:function (sexAppeal) { // property `is` references this unnamed function defined right here
        // inside the function the first argument can be referenced as `sexAppeal`
        sexAppeal = true; // override the value of `sexAppeal` to be `true`
        if (!arguments[0]) { // `arguments[0]` is the original value of the first argument
            console.log("JavaScript is " + this.sexy()); // prints `Javascript is Sexy!`
        }
    }
};
JavaScript.is(); // call the unnamed (`is`) function above with `this === JavaScript` and `sexAppeal === undefined`
```

Extra: the ternary condition is true because `this.sexy` === `JavaScript.sexy` which is a function (and functions are objects which all evaluate to true).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you've got most problem with is this:

```
function sexy() {
    return this.sexy ? ("ugly. Rails is HOT.","Sexy!") : "no Python.";
}
```

which indeed defines global function `sexy`. Let's change this code a little, so it will start to make sense.

```
JavaScript = { 
    sexy: function() {
        return this.sexy ? ("ugly. Rails is HOT.","Sexy!") : "no Python.";
    },
    is:function (sexAppeal) {
        sexAppeal = true;
        if (!arguments[0]) {
            console.log("JavaScript is " + this.sexy());
        }
    }
};
```

All better. While now the function isn't global, it shows us what it does - if `this.sexy` is defined within this object (which it is), returns `("ugly. Rails is HOT.","Sexy!")` - which enumerates to `"Sexy!"` due to `,` operator (try in console `0,1` or `1,0` or `a,b`).

With the default syntax, we would be able to create any amount of objects (and "classes") and make the function sexy access their properties.

Now what happens in the `Javascript` block.

<strike>The first thing is `is`. `Is` is a reserved word and shouldn't be used - while it will work in Chrome, it won't in IE (i'm fairly sure it can't be used in IE8, at the moment my local IE updated itself, so can't really test it).</strike> (looking at [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) can't confirm that `is` is indeed a reserved keyword, though I'm fairly sure IE complained about it. Maybe it's my dementia kicking in). What is interesting with `is` function is that it shows that parameters in JS can be overloaded. Meaning:

```
var a = function()
{
   arguments[0] = 'a';
   console.log(arguments[0]);
}

a();
```

will output 'a';

Your thought process was correct - hopefully my explanations over the bits make sense

Comment: Thanks, I really benefitted from seeing the rewrite of the function in your first code block above. And the example of 'overloading' `arguments[0]` above is interesting. It also led me to wonder why the author of the original example function bothered overloading via `sexAppeal = true;` since I think `if (!arguments[0])` on the next line will evaluate to true anyway.

Comment: That's good point you're making - while `arguments` array is overloadable, the variables created in the function scope are copies. Thus, while `sexAppeal` value is true, the arguments[0] is still `undefined`.